# A function to detect words vs numbers in a row & move them?

Tags: r

Was wondering if there's any function/package that I can use in R to detect & differentiate word and numbers in a column of df and move them to another column?
Not trying to move just certain words, but all that are letters/words.

Something like:

| Name | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3423423 |  |
| Kelly | 24241 |  |
| Tim | 30989 |  |
| Siobhan | Tuscon |  |
| Jim | Arizona |  |

to

| Name | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3423423 |  |
| Kelly | 24241 |  |
| Tim | 30989 |  |
| Siobhan |  | Tuscon |
| Jim |  | Arizona |

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do this using regex -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(condition = grepl('^\\d+$', Value),
         Value1 = ifelse(condition, Value, ''), 
         Value2 = ifelse(!condition, Value, '')) %>%
  select(-condition, -Value)

#     Name  Value1  Value2
#1    John 3423423        
#2   Kelly   24241        
#3     Tim   30989        
#4 Siobhan          Tuscon
#5     Jim         Arizona
```

`'^\\d+$'` returns `TRUE` for values which has all numbers in them.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "Kelly", "Tim", "Siobhan", "Jim"
), Value = c("3423423", "24241", "30989", "Tuscon", "Arizona"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `str_remove` with `regex`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Value1 = str_remove(Value,"[0-9].*"),
         Value=str_remove(Value,"^[A-Za-z]+$"))
```

```
     Name   Value  Value1
1    John 3423423        
2   Kelly   24241        
3     Tim   30989        
4 Siobhan          Tuscon
5     Jim         Arizona
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   extract(Value, into = c("Value", "Value1"), "^(\\d+)?(.*)")
     Name   Value  Value1
1    John 3423423        
2   Kelly   24241        
3     Tim   30989        
4 Siobhan          Tuscon
5     Jim         Arizona
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "Kelly", "Tim", "Siobhan", "Jim"
), Value = c("3423423", "24241", "30989", "Tuscon", "Arizona"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```